# Comparing urls with slash and www

Tags: python, url, web, uri

Are urls listed below the same or equal?

```
1. http://example.com
2. http://www.example.com
3. http://example.com/
```

How to compare those urls in python for equality if they are same?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They are not the same. They _could_ all return the same content, or not, depending on the setup of the web server.

Comment: @MarkkuK.whats the difference between them. Where www is used and where not its used similarly, when / can be used and where not....

Comment: All I'm saying is that 1, 2, and 3 are different strings, so they don't _necessarily_ refer to the same content. In practice, they often do, but they don't have to.

Answer (score 2):

You can split up entire URL into parts:

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> urlparse.urlparse('http://www.example.com')
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.example.com', path='', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> urlparse.urlparse('http://example.com')
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='example.com', path='', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

If you assume that all URLs are come from the same domain, but sometimes are prefixed with "www", you could just compare "path" component. It depends on your particular task.

Answer (score 0):

No need to reinvent the wheel.

Use this REGEX designed for parsing URLs.

http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls

Comment: I saw only regex codes. But how to use that regex code so that two urls could be compared?

Comment: These regex patterns remove all unnecessary characters, so you pass your URL's into these REGEX Patterns, it will return the base URL (for your example. http: / /example.com becomes "example.com" and if you test that against http:/ /w w w.example.com passed into the regex, it will also return "example.com" so they will be the same. Edit: stupid StackOverflow auto formatting my URLs.

Comment: I tried it with python using following code:
import re
# coding=utf-8
def urlValidation(url):
 regex = re.compile(r'(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:''".,<>?«»“”‘’]))', re.IGNORECASE)
 result = re.match(regex, url)
 return result

print urlValidation('http://example.com/')

But got meaningless result:
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10e5e2d20>